# Access, two fields relating to one table

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to setup a database but I have run into some trouble.
I have a table containing all measuring devices on a factory, those devices use two gasses to operate. Gas_1 and Gas_2.
What I want to make is this:

Table_Devices
-device Name(unique)
-Gas_1 ID
-Gas_2 ID
etc

Table_Gasses
-Gas ID(unique)
-Gas type
-Expiration date
-Gas Pressure
etc

I want to relate both "Gas_1 ID" and "Gas_2 ID" to the "Gas ID" in Table_Gasses.
However It seems that when I try to relate them, It wil only display the data if both the "Gas_1 ID" and "Gas_2 ID" are the same as the "Gas ID" in the "Table_Gasses" table.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Weclome to stackoverflow.  Please provide your query and the faulty results.  There's always a "way to fix" things, but we need to see more detials.

Comment: Two fields can reference the same table as source for a combobox or listbox list. Each field can certainly save a different value. If setting Relationship then you need to pull Table_Gasses into the Relationship builder twice. They will show as Table_Gasses and Table_Gasses_1.